# How do those glowing LED faucet aerators power themselves?

Tags: electrical, shower, faucet, led

Do a web search for [`LED faucet aerator`](https://www.google.com/search?q=led%20faucet%20aerator) and you'll see dozens of different color-changing faucet aerators (and [showers](https://www.google.com/search?q=led%20shower%20head)), most of which are powered just from the stream of water. How do they generate the necessary power? Is there a teenie turbine and generator? Some sort of oscillating fin on a piezoelectric bar? Gnomes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the [LDR 530 2165TL LED Faucet Aerator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1NLDY2) they explain that it:

> Runs entirely on the water stream pressure from your faucet - no batteries required

On another [LED Light Water Faucet](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-3-Color-Sensor-LED-Light-Water-Faucet-Tap-Temperature-For-kitchen-Bathroom-/151656397176) they show the impeller:

[image: impeller]

And [here](http://mujia.en.alibaba.com/product/1881583977-209419477/LS04_Singel_hole_Deck_mounted_led_lighted_faucet_aerator.html) they explain:

> There is a small dynamo with impeller inside the faucet. When you turn on the faucet, the impeller will start to move by water flowing and make the dynamo work.
>
> The LED will change its color according to different water temperature:
>
> A. Water temperature ≤77°F(25°C), Water color is blue
>
> B. 77°F(25°C)<Water temperature < 104°F(40°C), Water color is green
>
> C. Water temperature≥104°F(40°C), Water color is red

Also see:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vePD8JpGiu0

Answer (score 4):

The one I had was powered by either AAA's or stacked "coin" type cells. That, combined with the 2 inches of space lost in the sink made me ditch the whole system. I don't doubt that some are powered with a small turbine (or something like it), but some are just battery powered.